# how to assign value for id attribute of image tag in visualforce page?

Tags: image, dynamic, salesforce

Am not able to assign the id value dynamically for an image...am referring this image javascript to display the up/down arrows accordingly...here is the code snippet...

```
<apex:variable var="count" value="{!1}"/>
<apex:image id="msn{!count}" url="{!URLFOR($Resource.style_resources, 'images/up-arrow.gif')}" alt="Open-close" />
```

but i get the compilation error as "literal value is expected for id"...

can't we dynamically assign the value for id attribute ??

Answer (score 1):

From [Apex image](http://%3Capex:image%20id=%22theImage%22%20value=%22/img/myimage.gif%22%20width=%22220%22%20height=%2255%22/%3E),

```
<apex:image id="theImage" value="/img/myimage.gif" width="220" height="55"/>
```

*The example above renders the following HTML:*

```
<img id="theImage" src="/img/myimage.gif" width="220" height="55"/>
```

So change

```
<apex:image id="msn{!count}" url="{!URLFOR($Resource.style_resources, 'images/up-arrow.gif')}" alt="Open-close" />
```

to

```
<img id="msn{!count}" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.style_resources, 'images/up-arrow.gif')}" alt="Open-close" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct you can't assign an element id dynamically. it has to be a string literal. I have however used the class attribute to create custom ids that can be later used in javascript. I do this with jQuery and it's powerful selectors to select elements based on tag type and class.

The example below is just a sample but with jQuery you can get pretty creative.

```
<apex:variable var="count" value="{!1}"/>
<apex:image id="msn" 
    url="{!URLFOR($Resource.style_resources, 'images/up-arrow.gif')}" 
    alt="Open-close"
    styleClass="msn{!count}" />

    <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"/>

    <script>
        jQuery.noConflict();

        function doSomethingWithImg() {
            try {
                var imgElement = jQuery('.msn1');

                /*Do what you need to do with the element*/
            } catch (e) { /*Ignore Error*/ }
        }
     </script>
```

Here is the link to jQuery selectors: [jQuery Selector Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)